# Imagen con mascara para Xamarin Forms

Tags: imagen, xamarin.forms, jquery-mask-plugin

Quiero crear una máscara para una Imagen como el siguiente ejemplo:
[image: Imagen1]

He intentado usar el plugin FFImageLoading con Transformation, pero no he podido hacer la forma triangular que se muestra en el ejemplo, ya que solo me cortaba los bordes desde el centro de la imagen.

Tampoco puedo poner para la imagen triangular el fondo blanco con el triangulo en alpha, porque quiero conseguir el siguiente resultado:

[image: Imagen 2]

¿Hay alguna forma de coger los pixeles del triangulo que están en alpha, y aplicarselos a la imagen cuadrada azul para así conseguir ese efecto?

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Bienvenido, podrias traducir la pregunta ya que el idioma oficial es el Español

Comment: Lo acabo de cambiar al español, gracias.